# How do I see key/value in an odoo 10 recordset?

Tags: python, odoo-10

I'm using pdb to debug a problem with my odoo. I can see the recordset I'm interested in, but I need to know what keys are available in it. Sure, I could guess that it'll probably have "name", "create date", and "id" - but what other useful things might be in there?

```
    (Pdb) variant.attribute_value_ids
    product.attribute.value(15,)
    (Pdb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    (Pdb) pp variant.attribute_value_ids.read()
    [{'__last_update': '2018-02-12 14:46:37',
    'attribute_id': (3, u'5-20 Acres'),
    'create_date': '2018-02-12 14:45:42',
    'create_uid': (40, u'User Name'),
    'display_name': u'5-20 Acres: 15-25',
    'id': 15,
    'name': u'15-25',
    'price_extra': 0.0,
    'price_ids': [],
    'product_ids': [195, 211, 235, 183, 189],
    'sequence': 3,
    'write_date': '2018-02-12 14:46:37',
    'write_uid': (40, u'User Name')}]
    (Pdb)
```